# Fill in spaces between polygon features, voronoi style

Tags: qgis, polygon, voronoi-thiessen

I'm looking for a way to merge polygons across the empty space between them with a Voronoi-type result. There is a very similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138175/create-polygons-from-many-small-expand-to-include-space-between), but the approaches outlined in the comments did not produce the result I wanted (it created too many extra polygons, and all were very jagged). So, I did it manually as you can see below. I'd like to know a way to do this non-manually as I have even more complicated polygons that need this treatment.

What I have (before merge):
[image: before merge]

What I want (after merge):
[image: after merge]

**Edit:** There's a buffering question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175599/buffer-neighbouring-polygons-without-overlap-using-qgis) that may be useful to me so long as I clip the resulting buffer's world extent, but so far it has no answer. Also in my case whenever I try buffering this shapefile, the rectangular ocean boundaries wind up getting buffered as well.

Comment: if you can get the land as polygons (rather than gaps) then this .might be a job for skeletonisation e.g. [v.voronoi with -s option](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.voronoi.html)..? Not tried this though

Comment: How would you do that while keeping the marine rectangles? I've never done skeletonization

Comment: Would you accept a raster based solution? I'm curious if a euclidean allocation type process in qgis or grass gis would work... The results from the raster process could be converted back to polygons.

Comment: @SaultDon totally! This is mostly for display purposes so as long as this raster-based solution preserves the rectangular borders within the ocean, it should work.